# Matching the hash character in Tatsu

Tags: python, tatsu

I am getting an exception attempting to parse the `#` character using Tatsu:

```
import tatsu

grammar = r'''
@@comments :: //
@@eol_comments :: //

start = '#' ;
'''

print(tatsu.__version__)

parser = tatsu.compile(grammar)
ast = parser.parse('#', trace=True)
```

```
5.8.3
↙start ~1:1
#
≢'#' 
≢start ~1:1
#

...

tatsu.exceptions.FailedToken: (1:1) expecting '#' :
#
^
start
```

If I change the `#` to `a` in both the grammar and the text then it is successful. I think the issue might be that `#` indicates a grammar comment in Tatsu, but I'm not sure how to escape it.

Comment: This is interesting. Let me take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `config.eol_comments_re` is not being overridden with the `@@eol_comments` definition.

Could you post an issue for this problem at https://github.com/neogeny/TatSu/issues?

The other problem is that comments should not be checked while parsing a `''` token.

Answer (score 0):

I researched this problem today for a long while, and found much room for improvement in TatSu.

Yet the conclusion is that `//` is a valid regex that matches zero input.

The solution in your case is to set the comments to strings you don't expect to find in the input:

```
    grammar = r'''
        @@comments :: /@@@@@@@/
        @@eol_comments :: /@@@@@@@/

        start = '#' ;
    '''
```

https://github.com/neogeny/TatSu/issues/303